# Show just CircleCI jobs (not workflow) as GitHub check

Tags: github, circleci

We have CircleCI hooked up to GitHub commits. Each commit triggers  a workflow with 4 jobs. These show on the PRs and commit status as 5 checks; the 4 expected and the workflow name:

[image: Screenshot of checks]

Is there a way to have just the 4 jobs without the workflow appearing as a check, i.e. not include `build_and_test` in the checks?

CircleCI `config.yml` snippet:

```yaml
version: 2.1

orbs:
  ruby: circleci/ruby@1.8.0

commands:
  # ...

jobs:
  # ...

workflows:
  build_and_test:
    jobs:
      - rspec
      - ruby-checks
      - javascript-checks
      - cypress-integration-tests
```

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because you've enabled the [GitHub Checks feature](https://circleci.com/docs/enable-checks/) which results in CircleCI workflows status being reported under the checks tab on GitHub.

This CircleCI feature installs a GitHub App (called "CircleCI Checks" in your repositories. So you'll need to remove that App from the repositories you don't want to have it in.

To do so:

1. Go to the repository Settings in GitHub
2. Under the "Integrations" section, click "GitHub Apps"
3. Click the "Configure" button corresponding to "CircleCI Checks"
4. There you can either select which repositories (if any) should have the App (`Repository access` section) or uninstall the "CircleCI Checks" App altogether (`Danger zone` section)